# GROUP BY retrieve from the history table the last event

Tags: mysql, date, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables and I want to retrieve from the history table the last event, so I wrote this request but the result is not good. or am i mistaken? thank you

```
    CREATE TABLE `equipment` (
      `id_equipment` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `reference` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'clé AIRO2',
      `buying_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `first_use` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `checking_delai` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `serial_number` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lot_number` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lapsing_date` date NOT NULL,
      `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      `inspection` date NOT NULL,
      `compteur` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_model` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `detruit` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `date_REEPREUVE` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `validite_apragaz` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `restituee_AJR` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `perdu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `maintenance_catt_o2` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `vendu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `colonne_inogen` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date changement colonne inogen',
      `rappel_525KS_dec19` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'rappel_cable_DEVILBISS_525_KS'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='matériel';

    CREATE TABLE `equipment_history` (
      `id_equipment_history` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `id_user` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `id_equipment` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_patient` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `tuyau` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `cable_alim` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `compteur` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `verif_alarme` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `verif_volume` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `verif_pression` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `verif_o2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `verif_debit` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `remplacer_consommable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `complet` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `comment_panne` text,
      `ras` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `panne` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_piece_jointe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='historique de l''utilisation du matériel';

    CREATE TABLE `patient_has_equipment` (
      `id_patient_has_equipment` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `id_intervention` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_equipment` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `id_patient` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
      `date_attribution` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `version_appli` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

request :

```
SELECT
    equipment.id_equipment,
    equipment.reference,
    history.updated,
    history.`status`
FROM
    equipment
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `equipment_history`
    GROUP BY
        id_equipment
    ORDER BY
        `equipment_history`.`updated`
    DESC
) AS history
ON
    history.id_equipment = equipment.id_equipment
WHERE
    history.`status` = 3 AND equipment.id_equipment NOT IN(
    SELECT
        id_equipment
    FROM
        patient_has_equipment
)
```

thanks

Comment: I removed the sqlserver tag, since the syntax indicates that you are running mysql. Please only tag one database at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group by` subquery is the problem. While this is a syntax error in most databases, MySQL - unfortunately - tolerates this syntax (when sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled), but does not do what you think: you actually an arbitary record from the table for each `equipment_id` (the `order by` clause has no effect on this behavior).

You need to filter for the last history record rather than aggregate. I think that this should do what you want:

```
select  
    e.id_equipment,
    e.reference,
    eh.updated,
    eh.status
from equipment e
inner join equipment_history eh on eh.id_equipment = e.id_equipment
where 
    eh.status = 3
    and eh.updated = (
        select max(eh1.updated) 
        from equipment_history eh1 
        where eh1.id_equipment = e.id_equipment
    )
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from patient_has_equipment phe
        where phe.id_equipment = e.id_equipment
    )
```